# Cron Job running extremely slow

Tags: cron, sh, ash

I have a cron job that calls a shell script.  The script sends POST requests to localhost using CURL.

Cron script:

```
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

0 0 * * * reboot now
2 11 * * 0 /bin/sh /usr/share/power/turn_off_outlets.sh
```

turn_off_outlets.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

#arg 1 is outlet and arg two is the relay state(true for on, false for off)
power_ctrl_outlet() {
  echo "Turning outlet $1 to $2"
  curl -X PUT http://localhost/restapi/relay/outlets/$1/state/ -H 'Acc: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46JGNpZW5jZQ==' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -d "value=$2"
}

turn_off_all_outlets() {
  power_ctrl_outlet 0 false
  power_ctrl_outlet 1 false
  power_ctrl_outlet 2 false
  power_ctrl_outlet 3 false
  power_ctrl_outlet 4 false
  power_ctrl_outlet 5 false
  power_ctrl_outlet 6 false
  power_ctrl_outlet 7 false
}


turn_off_all_outlets
```

Running the script from the command line works fine but when cron executes the script it takes a very very long time.  I have tried using `nice` to set the priority level but that slows the entire system.

The system is `BusyBox v1.22.1 () built-in shell (ash)`

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: I expect your code to fail completely, since it's calling a function called `turn_off_all_outlets` but defining one called `turn_on_all_outlets`.

Comment: Whoops, I was grabbing parts of the script that are relevant, fixed that.

Comment: Same here, why are network request so slow from cron threads?